# Barcode is hidden in reporting services

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, reporting, barcode

I have a report which carries a barcode , at the time of the `Visual Studio` preview it looks perfectly but when published to the server reporting services ( WEB ) does not show me the barcode as if hidden

This is the code I use within the report :

```
Public Shared Function Code39(ByVal stringText As String) As Byte()
        Dim result As Byte() = Nothing

        Try
            result = GenerateImage("Code 3 de 9", StringToBarcode39String(stringText))
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try

        Return result
    End Function

    Public Shared Function Code128(ByVal stringText As String) As Byte()
        Dim result As Byte() = Nothing

        Try
            result = GenerateImage("Code 128", StringToBarcode128String(stringText))
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try

        Return result
    End Function

    Public Shared Function GenerateImage(ByVal fontName As String, ByVal stringText As String) As Byte()
        Dim oGraphics As System.Drawing.Graphics
        Dim barcodeSize As System.Drawing.SizeF
        Dim ms As System.IO.MemoryStream

        Using font As New System.Drawing.Font(New System.Drawing.FontFamily(fontName), 36)
            Using tmpBitmap As New System.Drawing.Bitmap(1, 1, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
                oGraphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(tmpBitmap)
                oGraphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixel
                barcodeSize = oGraphics.MeasureString(stringText, font)
                oGraphics.Dispose()
            End Using

            Using newBitmap As New System.Drawing.Bitmap(barcodeSize.Width, barcodeSize.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
                oGraphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(newBitmap)
                oGraphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixel

                Using oSolidBrushWhite As New System.Drawing.SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.White)
                    Using oSolidBrushBlack As New System.Drawing.SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Black)
                        oGraphics.FillRectangle(oSolidBrushWhite, New System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, barcodeSize.Width, barcodeSize.Height))
                        oGraphics.DrawString(stringText, font, oSolidBrushBlack, 0, 0)
                    End Using

                End Using

                ms = New System.IO.MemoryStream()
                newBitmap.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
            End Using
        End Using

        Return ms.ToArray()
    End Function

    Public Shared Function StringToBarcode128String(ByVal value As String) As String
        ' Parameters : a string
        ' Return     : a string which give the bar code when it is dispayed with CODE128.TTF font
        '            : an empty string if the supplied parameter is no good
        Dim charPos As Integer, minCharPos As Integer
        Dim currentChar As Integer, checksum As Integer
        Dim isTableB As Boolean = True, isValid As Boolean = True
        Dim returnValue As String = String.Empty

        If value.Length > 0 Then

            ' Check for valid characters
            For charCount As Integer = 0 To value.Length - 1
                'currentChar = char.GetNumericValue(value, charPos);
                currentChar = AscW(Char.Parse(value.Substring(charCount, 1)))
                If Not (currentChar >= 32 AndAlso currentChar <= 126) Then
                    isValid = False
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next

            ' Barcode is full of ascii characters, we can now process it
            If isValid Then
                charPos = 0
                While charPos < value.Length
                    If isTableB Then
                        ' See if interesting to switch to table C
                        ' yes for 4 digits at start or end, else if 6 digits
                        If charPos = 0 OrElse charPos + 4 = value.Length Then
                            minCharPos = 4
                        Else
                            minCharPos = 6
                        End If


                        minCharPos = IsNumber(value, charPos, minCharPos)

                        If minCharPos < 0 Then
                            ' Choice table C
                            If charPos = 0 Then
                                ' Starting with table C
                                ' char.ConvertFromUtf32(210);
                                returnValue = (ChrW(210)).ToString()
                            Else
                                ' Switch to table C
                                returnValue = returnValue & (ChrW(204)).ToString()
                            End If
                            isTableB = False
                        Else
                            If charPos = 0 Then
                                ' Starting with table B
                                ' char.ConvertFromUtf32(209);
                                returnValue = (ChrW(209)).ToString()

                            End If
                        End If
                    End If

                    If Not isTableB Then
                        ' We are on table C, try to process 2 digits
                        minCharPos = 2
                        minCharPos = IsNumber(value, charPos, minCharPos)
                        If minCharPos < 0 Then
                            ' OK for 2 digits, process it
                            currentChar = Integer.Parse(value.Substring(charPos, 2))
                            currentChar = IIf(currentChar < 95, currentChar + 32, currentChar + 105) ''
                            returnValue = returnValue & (ChrW(currentChar)).ToString()
                            charPos += 2
                        Else
                            ' We haven't 2 digits, switch to table B
                            returnValue = returnValue & (ChrW(205)).ToString()
                            isTableB = True
                        End If
                    End If
                    If isTableB Then
                        ' Process 1 digit with table B
                        returnValue = returnValue & value.Substring(charPos, 1)
                        charPos += 1
                    End If
                End While

                ' Calculation of the checksum
                checksum = 0
                For [loop] As Integer = 0 To returnValue.Length - 1
                    currentChar = AscW(Char.Parse(returnValue.Substring([loop], 1)))
                    currentChar = IIf(currentChar < 127, currentChar - 32, currentChar - 105)
                    If [loop] = 0 Then
                        checksum = currentChar
                    Else
                        checksum = (checksum + ([loop] * currentChar)) Mod 103
                    End If
                Next

                ' Calculation of the checksum ASCII code
                checksum = IIf(checksum < 95, checksum + 32, checksum + 105)
                ' Add the checksum and the STOP
                returnValue = returnValue & (ChrW(checksum)).ToString() & (ChrW(211)).ToString()
            End If
        End If

        Return returnValue
    End Function


    Private Shared Function IsNumber(ByVal InputValue As String, ByVal CharPos As Integer, ByVal MinCharPos As Integer) As Integer
        ' if the MinCharPos characters from CharPos are numeric, then MinCharPos = -1
        MinCharPos -= 1
        If CharPos + MinCharPos < InputValue.Length Then
            While MinCharPos >= 0
                If AscW(Char.Parse(InputValue.Substring(CharPos + MinCharPos, 1))) < 48 OrElse AscW(Char.Parse(InputValue.Substring(CharPos + MinCharPos, 1))) > 57 Then
                    Exit While
                End If
                MinCharPos -= 1
            End While
        End If
        Return MinCharPos
    End Function

    Public Shared Function StringToBarcode39String(ByVal value As String, Optional ByVal addChecksum As Boolean = False) As String
        ' Parameters : a string
        ' Return     : a string which give the bar code when it is dispayed with CODE128.TTF font
        '            : an empty string if the supplied parameter is no good
        Dim isValid As Boolean = True
        Dim currentChar As Char
        Dim returnValue As String = String.Empty
        Dim checksum As Integer = 0
        If value.Length > 0 Then

            'Check for valid characters
            For CharPos As Integer = 0 To value.Length - 1
                currentChar = Char.Parse(value.Substring(CharPos, 1))
                If Not ((currentChar >= "0"c AndAlso currentChar <= "9"c) OrElse (currentChar >= "A"c AndAlso currentChar <= "Z"c) OrElse currentChar = " "c OrElse currentChar = "-"c OrElse currentChar = "."c OrElse currentChar = "$"c OrElse currentChar = "/"c OrElse currentChar = "+"c OrElse currentChar = "%"c) Then
                    isValid = False
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
            If isValid Then
                ' Add start char
                returnValue = "*"
                ' Add other chars, and calc checksum
                For CharPos As Integer = 0 To value.Length - 1
                    currentChar = Char.Parse(value.Substring(CharPos, 1))
                    returnValue += currentChar.ToString()
                    If currentChar >= "0"c AndAlso currentChar <= "9"c Then
                        checksum = checksum + AscW(currentChar) - 48
                    ElseIf currentChar >= "A"c AndAlso currentChar <= "Z"c Then
                        checksum = checksum + AscW(currentChar) - 55
                    Else
                        Select Case currentChar
                            Case "-"c
                                checksum = checksum + AscW(currentChar) - 9
                                Exit Select
                            Case "."c
                                checksum = checksum + AscW(currentChar) - 9
                                Exit Select
                            Case "$"c
                                checksum = checksum + AscW(currentChar) + 3
                                Exit Select
                            Case "/"c
                                checksum = checksum + AscW(currentChar) - 7
                                Exit Select
                            Case "+"c
                                checksum = checksum + AscW(currentChar) - 2
                                Exit Select
                            Case "%"c
                                checksum = checksum + AscW(currentChar) + 5
                                Exit Select
                            Case " "c
                                checksum = checksum + AscW(currentChar) + 6
                                Exit Select
                        End Select
                    End If
                Next
                ' Calculation of the checksum ASCII code
                If addChecksum Then
                    checksum = checksum Mod 43
                    If checksum >= 0 AndAlso checksum <= 9 Then
                        returnValue += (ChrW(checksum + 48)).ToString()
                    ElseIf checksum >= 10 AndAlso checksum <= 35 Then
                        returnValue += (ChrW(checksum + 55)).ToString()
                    Else
                        Select Case checksum
                            Case 36
                                returnValue += "-"
                                Exit Select
                            Case 37
                                returnValue += "."
                                Exit Select
                            Case 38
                                returnValue += " "
                                Exit Select
                            Case 39
                                returnValue += "$"
                                Exit Select
                            Case 40
                                returnValue += "/"
                                Exit Select
                            Case 41
                                returnValue += "+"
                                Exit Select
                            Case 42
                                returnValue += "%"
                                Exit Select
                        End Select
                    End If
                End If
                ' Add stop char
                returnValue += "*"
            End If
        End If
        Return returnValue
    End Function
```

- Do I use assemblies , And the barcode image is kind

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that on the server the barcode font is missing?